# How to copy specify sub folder to destination by ansible

Tags: ansible

Hi I have a folder with following structure.

```
/data/srcA/sub1
/data/srcA/sub2
/data/srcA/sub3

/data/srcB/sub1
/data/srcB/sub2
/data/srcB/sub3

...

/data/srcZ/sub1
/data/srcZ/sub2
/data/srcZ/sub3
```

But I just want copy sub1 & sub3 to the dest machine's folder dest.

then the dest folder will look like

```
/dest/srcA/sub1
/dest/srcA/sub3

/dest/srcB/sub1
/dest/srcB/sub3
...

/dest/srcZ/sub1
/dest/srcZ/sub3
```

Are there easy way to do this by Ansible?

Thank you~

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module [synchronize](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/synchronize_module.html) should help to do it. (You will need to fit the parameters to the locations of src and dest.)

```
- name: Synchronize passing in extra rsync options
  synchronize:
    src: /data/
    dest: /dest/
    rsync_opts:
      - "--exclude=sub2/"
```